# Triple product formula on $K = \mathrm{SU}(2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $K = \mathrm{SU}(2) = \{ k[\alpha ,\beta] \mid \alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb{C}, |\alpha |^2 + |\beta |^2 = 1 \} $ with
$$ k [ \alpha , \beta ] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha & \beta \\
    - \overline{\beta} & \overline{\alpha}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Let $V_n$ denote the space of polynomials in one variable of degree at most $n$.  We choose the set $\{ z^{l-q} : q\in\mathbb{Z},\  |q|\leq l\}$ as a basis for $V_{2l}$. Then the (irreducible and unitary) representations of $K$ are given by the formula
$$ \sigma_l(k [\alpha , \beta]) z^{l-q} = ( \alpha z - \overline{\beta} )^{l-q} (  \beta  z + \overline{\alpha})^{l+q} .$$
Let $ \Phi_{p,q}^l $ denote the coefficient of $z^{l-p}$ in the polynomial expansion of $\sigma_l(k [\alpha , \beta]) z^{l-q}$. i.e,
$$ \sum_{|p|\leq l} \Phi_{p,q}^l(k[\alpha,\beta]) z^{l-p} = ( \alpha z - \overline{\beta} )^{l-q} (  \beta  z + \overline{\alpha})^{l+q} ,\quad for \ |q|\leq l. $$

There is an explicit formula of
$$ \int_K \Phi_{p,q}^l(k) \overline{\Phi_{p_1,q_1}^{l_1}(k)} dk$$
in the book *[Sum Formula for SL2 over Imaginary Quadratic Number Fields](https://dokumen.tips/documents/sum-formula-for-sl2-over-imaginary-quadratic-number-fields-za-sumirae-za-sl-2.html?page=23)* by Lokvenec-Guleska.

I have to solve the triple product
$$ \int_K \Phi_{p,q}^l(k) \Phi_{p_1,q_1}^{l_1}(k) \Phi_{p_2,q_2}^{l_2}(k) dk.$$

I know how to compute this equation through brute force. However, my advisor doesn’t want me to include the complex calculation process in my paper. Is there a place where I can directly find this formula? Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks!

---

In fact I have obtained the following formula: For any $a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k = k[\alpha,\beta]$, we have
$$\int_K \alpha^{a}  \bar{\alpha} ^{b} \beta^{c}  \bar{\beta} ^{d} d k = \delta ( a=b, c=d ) \frac{a!c!}{(a+c+1)!},$$
where $\delta$ denotes the Kronecker symbol.

Comment: The corresponding post on [math.se]: [Triple Product Formula on $K = SU(2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4798283). On meta, you can find some basic advice about [cross-posting](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/cross-posting/info) - it is recommended to provide at least a link.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know of a specific source, but have you tried looking up the literature on Weingarten calculus, and does it help? e.g. the expository article of Collins-Matsumoto-Novak https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14890

Comment: In physicists language, aren’t you trying to compute triple products of Wigner D-matrices ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @DavidLehavi I haven't heard of that thing ...

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you for your suggestion! However this article seems to be unrelated to my field of expertise,  I might need some time to understand it. (╥﹏╥)

Comment: Well, if you haven't heard about them, here they are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Relation_to_Wigner_D-matrices

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those questions like

[Determinant of the random matrix $X^2+Y^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456641/determinant-of-the-random-matrix-x2y2)

which are extremely easy to do if one is familiar with graphical/diagrammatic algebra, but would otherwise lead to rather cumbersome calculations.

The rules for computing $SU(2)$ or more general $SU(N)$ normalized Haar integrals were explained in my two answers to MO question

[How to constructively/combinatorially prove Schur-Weyl duality?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255492/how-to-constructively-combinatorially-prove-schur-weyl-duality)

In the present situation, the triple product integral, should be some sign and harmless ratio of factorials times a product of two [Wigner $3jm$ symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol)
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
l_1 & l_2 & l\\
p_1 & p_2 & -(p_1+p_2)
\end{array}\right)
\times
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
l_1 & l_2 & l\\
q_1 & q_2 & -(q_1+q_2)
\end{array}\right)
$$